# @JsonIgnore not working in a different Environment

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

This is the bean class in which I am using @JsonIgnore. My test case passed and I do not see catColor in the JSON in local environment but in Dev environment I am still able to see catColor in the JSON. Please let me know if I have to make any changes in the code or should I check anything in the environment.

JSON:

```
{"catName":"","catEyes":"","catDetails":"","catColor":"" }
```

CatBean.java

```
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

   @XmlRootElement
   @SuppressWarnings("PMD")
   public class CatBean {

       private String catName;
       private String catEyes;
       private String catDetails;


       public String getCatName(){
           return catName;
       } 

       public void setCatName(String catName){
           this.catName=catName;
       } 

       public String getCatEyes(){
           return catEyes;
       } 

       public void setCatEyes(String catEyes){
           this.catEyes=catEyes;
       } 

       public String getCatDetails(){
           return catDetails;
       } 

       public void setCatDetails(String catDetails){
           this.catDetails=catDetails;
       } 

       @JsonIgnore
       public String getCatColor() {  
           return getCatDetails(catColor);   
       }    
  }
```

CatDetails.java

```
    public class CatDetails {

        private String name;
        private String value;


        public String getName() {
           return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

```
    build.gradle ( Gradle imports)

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.9.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.9'
```

I do not have a field defined as `catColor`. I am using `Java 7`  and `Gradle 4.10.3` both in local and Dev.

It is working in local but It is not working in Dev. I wrote a JUNIT Test case to test the JSON.

(Test Case to check the JSON Being created)

```
    @Test
    public void testJsonResponseNotContainingCardPresent() throws HostAuthException, ISOParseException, ParseException, IOException {

        CatBean catBean= new CatBean();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String catBeanAsString = Mapper.writeValueAsString(catBean);     

        assertThat(requestBeanAsString,not(containsString("catColor")));

    }
```

Comment: can you give us a little bit more input?

Comment: like: show us the complete file and the error...

Comment: There is no error. But I am able to see the field in the JSON that is being created. I will add the entire file here.

Comment: when I copy & paste your code, it's already not compiling. can you please fix your code to make it realistic?

Comment: Worth checking if exactly the same code is deployed to DEV environment

Comment: I tested it back in local and I see JsonIgnore not working in local also.